# How to get parent email of a email in ews?

Tags: email, outlook, exchangewebservices

I'm developing simple application that uses EWS(Exchange Web Service) to manage emails , there is a requirement to find the parent email of a email , I can get conversation id to find emails include one conversation , but how do I get parent email of a selected email ?
is there any property that has parent Email id or something?

Comment: https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html ?

Comment: I mean ews managed api c#